# Stackable real time clock?

Tags: rtc

I'm using Pibrella on my Pi (Model B+) and now I need RTC functionality. Are there stackable RTC modules that you know of?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Kevin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are a number of RTC options for RPI. The *RTC Pi* is stackable. *RasClock* is not stackable, but it's very small. For soldering people, there are also a lot of tutorials on DIY options online. This is all fairly easy to search for using your favourite internet search engine.

Comment: Thank you, Bex. I have been unsuccessfully searching for information about stacking the Pibrella board onto, for example, the RTC Pi.